# r training a datetime stamp model using glm/binomial

Tags: r, machine-learning, logistic-regression

I have a data model with `m`, `k` (both numeric), `startTimeStamp` (Posix) and `isProcessActive` (true/false)

I have collected these data for over 5 days, each row represents one minute, around 300 minutes of data. (Some days will be missing). Dropped `EndTimeStamp` column as glm summary comes out insignificant for this data point.

IsProcessActive is based on either

1. `m` or `k` > 500
2. diff between previous and current `startTimeStamp` > 65 seconds or < 18 minutes, `m` or `k` can be 0 or greater than 0.

Sample data:

```
m      k   startTimeStamp            IsProcessActive 

550     0     1st March 2018, 11:00AM        1
1550    11    1st March 2018, 11:02AM        1
5       0     1st March 2018, 11:05AM        1
50      50    1st March 2018, 11:06AM        0
0       0     1st March 2018, 11:08AM        0
0       0     1st March 2018, 11:18AM        1
```

Using glm with binomial link, output prediction works for any/all combinations of `m` and/or `k`. But always fails predict for `startTimeStamp` difference > 65 seconds with `m` & `k` being 0.

Hope I'm explaining myself clear. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

At last this issue is fixed by 2 changes.

## 1. Replace startTimeStamp with diffTime, which is calculated difference in time (in seconds) between previous and current observation. If this value is either > 65 or < 1200, the isProcessActive is set to 1, irrespective of other 2 values.

## 2.  glm still fails to predict, so switched to randomForest. Now i have 90% accuracy with almost 95% of diffTime predicted.